# Unable to locate package libssl-dev and I cant find a solution

Tags: package-management, kali

I am trying to install libssl-dev but I keep getting error "Unable to locate package libssl-dev"

Comment: Are you using Kali?

Comment: Kali Linux is a Debian-based distribution with a collection of security and forensics tools. .... Has nothing to do with Ubuntu !

Comment: Add following repositories:

[https://packages.debian.org/sid/libssl-dev](libssl-dev)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
apt-cache search libssl
```

to find out if it is available for you.

Also, make sure, your repositories are correctly configured:

[19.10 sources.list](https://gist.github.com/malikalichsan/860b8134a74c65a394efe09711d0b95f)
[18.04 sources.list](https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1)
[16.04 sources.list](https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1)

Kali is not supported here, but the same is applied to it also: *make sure your [repositories](https://gist.github.com/kuamit5516/99897918fd94e8c5310c370f3211e83e) are configured correctly*

After repositories correction, use `sudo apt update` and then recheck.

On 19.10 with correctly configured repositories `apt-cache search` returns:

```
$ apt-cache search libssl-dev
libssl-dev - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
perl-openssl-defaults - version compatibility baseline for Perl OpenSSL packages
```

**20.04 sources.list**:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v "#"

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse                                                                                              

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse                                                                    

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

Comment: Indeed it turned out that my sources.list was totally broken! Thanks!