# Unable to locate package openssl-dev

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install the ROOT CERN packages on linux, using Ubuntu 18.04, and whenever I get into the prerequisites download, with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev cmake g++ gcc binutils libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev python openssl-dev
```

I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openssl-dev
```

I've tried correcting this by configurating my repository as was suggested in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220039/unable-to-locate-package-libssl-dev-and-i-cant-find-a-solution), yet the problem still persisted.

Would like to know how is it possible to fix this. Thank you.

Edit:

The complete output of the `sudo apt update` command is:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

I've also tried installing the libssl-dev package with `sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev` and the outcome remains unchanged.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1293801/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: The prerequisite list [here](https://root.cern/install/dependencies/#required-packages-1) says *"openssl-dev or libssl-dev"* - have you tried installing the latter instead?